# find_by with json array executing a query with IN instead of searching for the whole array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

i have a model (area) with a jsonb field (coordinates):

```rb
  create_table "areas" do |t|
    t.jsonb "coordinates"
  end
```

now if i insert an array:

```rb
Area.create(coordinates: [1, 2])
```

it works fine, but searching for it:

```rb
Area.find_by(coordinates: [1, 2])
```

executes an SQL query with IN, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT "areas".* FROM "areas" WHERE "areas"."coordinates" IN ($1, $2) LIMIT $3  [["coordinates", "1"], ["coordinates", "2"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

i tried searching for `[[1, 2]]` and `[[[1, 2]]]` but i always get the `IN` query.

(maybe it's a rails issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```rb
Area.find_by("coordinates = '[1, 2]'")
```

Comment: Not even close. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE

Comment: thanks, exactly what i was looking for, it works fine, but not with the prepared queries, e.g. `Area.where("coordinates = '?'", [1, 2])` doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You have to use SQL strings when querying JSON/Array/Hstore type columns. For example:

```
Event.where("payload->>'kind' = ?", "user_renamed")
```

They are not a "native" part of the query interface as creating the queries is much more involved than for a normal column due to typing and differing implementations. ActiveRecord will just create queries for these types as if it where normal column type that it understands. See [Active Record and PostgreSQL](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html).

Querying an array inside a json column can be done with something like:

```
WHERE coordinates @> ANY (ARRAY [1,2,3]::jsonb[]);
```

But - maybe you should just reconsider if using a JSON column is good idea in the first place as the queries are going to be horrible? JSON/JSONB types are good for certain specialized tasks where the data cannot conform to a schema but should not be a replacement for proper relational db modeling. Unnecessary JSONB is an antipattern.

Also if these are geographical coordinates you're representing those numbers either as integers or floats but there is no way to specificy the type in JSON besides adding a `.` and the parser desides if `2.0` is a float or an integer.

If you setup a separate table for coordinates you can actually use the and use ActiveRecord assocations and have a degree of data normalization, indexes, referential integrity and so on. Oh, and did I mention that you can actually query your data like a sane person?

```
class Area
  has_many :coordinates
end

# rails g model coordinate area:references lat:decimal lng:decimal
class Cooridinate
  belongs_to :area
end


Area.joins(:coordinates).where(coordinates: { lat: 1, lng: 1 })
```

You could also use the [PostGIS extension](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter) which provides specialized column types for coordinates, polygons, and other kinds of geographical stuff.

Comment: (your two first queries [don't work in my case](https://gist.github.com/dorian-marie-france/e474fce71ca0943f9c5eb98acb4c72d8)) i'm just going to have comma-separated coordinates (it's actually coordinates of a polygon) so it's easier to query. i used json/jsonb for objects and that's where it works fine. and for PostGIS this is just a hobby project but might come useful later and would probably migrate the data to that, thanks. (edit: okay not the comma separated solution, might move to a coordinates table like you suggested)

Comment: That's not the right takeaway as that's probably the worst way possible but hey if it floats your boat.

Comment: i actually ended up using a `geometry` field because the list of coordinates can be for a Polygon or a MultiPolygon (from geojson data). And as it's an object instead of an array there is no issue with querying the data